# Merging data from multiple files

Tags: linux, microsoft-excel, merge

So in my case I have multiple Linux VM's and each one of them there is a file called
`output.txt` (or other extension like excel?). They look like:

```
Average download time:8647
Average whatever : 153
```

Now I want to merge them all into one file with the average results from all files.
Which files extension is best to use or how it can be done with simple txt?

Comment: Are the files in plain text format, or microsoft excel, or something else? What exactly are in the two (or more) different files, and how exactly do you want to merge them? Just cat them all together, or add some numbers (which ones) and find their averages?

Comment: I've catted them together and used the following awk

awk '
  {
  c[$1]++; 
  for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
    s[$1"."i]+=$i};
  } 
  END {
    for (k in c) {
      printf "%s\t", k; 
      for(i=2;i<NF;i++) printf "%.1f\t", s[k"."i]/c[k]; 
      printf "%.1f\n", s[k"."NF]/c[k];
    }
  }' full.txt >> resulting.txt

Comment: Is that your own answer then? You could post it as an answer, and editing samples of the files into the original question would be helpful too

Answer (score 0):

I've cat them together and used the following awk script 
awk ' { c[$1]++; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) { s[$1"."i]+=$i}; } END { for (k in c) { printf "%s\t", k; for(i=2;i> resulting.txt

which redirects from input file:
a:123
b:213
a:234
b:42 and so on to get the average values